# SimpleCursorAdapter vs BaseAdapter

Tags: android, adapter

What is the benefit of using SimpleCursorAdapter over BaseAdapter?
In which scenarios BaseAdapter is more suitable and in which scenarios
SimpleCursorAdapter is more suitable ?

Also as in the documentation for SimpleCursorAdapter, it is written that

> This constructor was deprecated in API level 11.
>   This option is discouraged, as it results in Cursor queries being performed on the application's UI thread and thus can cause poor responsiveness or even Application Not Responding errors. As an alternative, use LoaderManager with a CursorLoader.

Does this mean that SimpleCursorAdapter should not be used even on lower API versions
eg. API level 10 (Gingerbread)?

The alternatives suggested - LoadManager & CursorLoader are only available for API level 11 & beyond. So what is the solution for working on API level 10 ?

Comment: LoaderManager and CursorLoader are part of the compatibility package, afaik.

Comment: What is deprecated is one constructor of simplecursoradapter, one that performs requeries on the main thread. Loaders would help you requery on background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the benefit of using SimpleCursorAdapter over BaseAdapter?

`SimpleCursorAdapter` encapsulates the logic of binding values from a `Cursor` to the subviews of your `ListView's` item. `BaseAdapter` is just an abstract class which can be inherited to provide a custom logic of initializing your `ListView`.

> In which scenarios BaseAdapter is more suitable and in which scenarios SimpleCursorAdapter is more suitable ?

If all you need is binding values from a `Cursor` to `Views` - go with the `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

> Does this mean that SimpleCursorAdapter should not be used even on lower API versions eg. API level 10 (Gingerbread)?

No, this isn't true, you can used it for any versions of Android.

> The alternatives suggested - LoadManager & CursorLoader are only available for API level 11 & beyond. So what is the solution for working on API level 10 ?

`LoaderManager` and `CursorLoader` are both available in the compatibility library, so you can use them on Android v4 and up. Hope this helps.